# how can i fix this debug (no such file)?

Tags: c, codeblocks

/I can't run any code and i recive that/

```
    Build messages :
    ||=== Build: Debug in tes (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
    obj\\Debug\\main.o||No such file or directory|
    ||error: no input files|
    ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|.
```

Comment: my crystal ball says that main.c (or maybe main.cpp) is not being compiled, or it has compiled with errors.  With the information provided, it is impossible to do more than random, wild guessing.  Try this - ditch codeblocks till you learn how to compile on the command line so you understand the steps involve when you invoke 'build' in codeblocks.

Comment: Have you tried reding [the user manual](https://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual/), or [the wiki](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Main_Page), or [the forums](https://forums.codeblocks.org)? Should have enough information to help you solve the problem, and the forums might be a better place to post this question.

Comment: And try to do a clean rebuild of everything, and post that log in your question.

Comment: The important line of the message seems to be this one: `obj\\Debug\\main.o||No such file or directory|`. You have failed to create the `main.o` object file which is needed to create and run the program. It's likely an error in the source.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HOW can i fix this problem in source